# d3.js - transition starting only without svg title, not with it

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js, transition

I found no direct answer for this, please forgive me if this has been covered differently in another topic.

I draw a bar chart which appears with a transition. I also want to add a tooltip which displays the value of data on mousehover.
Using the code below I have managed to obtain either the tooltip or the transition, but never the 2 together, which is my objective.

```
chart.selectAll(".bar")
.data(data)
.enter()
.append("rect")
.attr("class", "bar")
.attr("fill", function(d) {return colorscale(colorize(d.age));})
.attr("x", function(d) {return xscale(d.name);})
.attr("y", height - 3)
.attr("height", 3)
.attr("width", xscale.rangeBand())

.append("title")
.text(function(d){return d.age;})

.transition()
.duration(1600)
.attr("y", function (d) {return yscale(d.age);})
.attr("height", function (d) {return height - yscale(d.age);}) ;
```

If I remove

```
.append("title")
.text(function(d){return d.age;})
```

Then my transition works fine. If I but those 2 lines back I can see my tooltip but I lose my transition.

Any suggestion would be appreciated!

You can see the result [here](http://s354756048.onlinehome.fr/Data%20Visualization/mbostock/english%20letters/englishletters.html)

Thank you

Comment: Setup a jsfiddle, so people can play with your code, it makes your question a lot more approachable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the transition to the `rect` and not the `title` element:

```
var sel = chart.selectAll(".bar")
  .data(data)
  .enter()
  .append("rect");

sel.append("title")
  .text(function(d){return d.age;});

sel.transition()
  .duration(1600)
  .attr("y", function (d) {return yscale(d.age);})
  .attr("height", function (d) {return height - yscale(d.age);}) ;
```